# How to build up connection of remote server with dynamic IP of internet router?

Tags: linux, networking

I need to know how to connect linux server with local internet router which is using Dynamic IP address. I used no-ip but for this I always need a local server with which the internet is connected and the application provided by no-ip.com is running continuously to track IP address changes.

Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks

Comment: so to be sure to understand it: you have a server at home, with a dynamic IP address, but using no-ip.com you have a dynamic name, so you always know it's IP address? Great! So you've solved the problem! Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh then I misunderstood your setup! Sorry. So, the server you want to connect **to** has a fixed IP address, just the device you want to connect **from** has a dynamic IP address? But that would not be a problem...

Comment: @MarcusMüller No I don't have a server in house. My device is connected with ethernet cable and I have a live linux server.

Comment: what is a "live linux server"? What is the problem you're actually encountering? Sorry, I really don't understand your descriptions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you suggest some solution because the dynamic ip of internet router is changing after some time and I have to check it and update it according in code

Comment: I don't understand the problem.